Connection timeout while connecting to smtp with spring boot starter email in docker
I am using spring-boot-starter-mail to send emails and also I am deploying my spring boot application with docker
I am unable to connect smtp server on any port with docker, while with host I am able to connect.
Also I am unable to connect to smtp with telnet after connnecting to docker container.
Anyone can help me to overcome this problem..
This is the error
Mail server connection failed. Failed messages: org.eclipse.angus.mail.util.MailConnectException: Couldn't connect to host, port: smtp.gmail.com, 587; timeout -1; nested exception is: java.net.ConnectException: Operation timed out

docker-compose.yml
version: '3'
services:
  ecommerce:
    image: ecommerce:latest
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ecommerce/Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
      - "587:587"
    networks:
      - app-network
networks:
  app-network:
    driver: bridge

Dockerfile
FROM openjdk:17-jdk-alpine

WORKDIR /app/ecommerce


COPY /ecommerce/main.jar /app/main.jar
COPY /ecommerce/env.properties /app/env.properties

EXPOSE 8080 587


ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "main.jar"]

Spring config
spring.mail.host=${EMAIL_HOST}
spring.mail.port=${EMAIL_PORT}
spring.mail.username=${EMAIL_USERNAME}
spring.mail.password=${EMAIL_PASSWORD}
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.auth=true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.enable=true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.ssl.enable=false

#INFO: those above variables are populating correctly

Things, I have tried

Expose PORT
Ensured firewall with ufw so that incoming and outgoing connections can go
Tried on all the different ports 25, 587, 433, etc

